# What is the validation of the available VM in case of deploying to Azure cloud service with existed VM?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I created a new VM of size `A5`. When I trying to add a new VM of size `Standard_D4` - There is a warning message

`All virtual machines in a domain name must be of sizes A5, A6, A7, Basic_A0, Basic_A1, Basic_A2, Basic_A3, Basic_A4, ExtraLarge, ExtraSmall, Large, Medium, Small, Standard_D1_v2, Standard_D11_v2, Standard_D12_v2, Standard_D13_v2, Standard_D14_v2, Standard_D2_v2, Standard_D3_v2, Standard_D4_v2, Standard_D5_v2. This virtual machine's size will be changed to 'Standard A5'.`

I don't understand this algorithm. If we already have a VM of some size `x`. How can I know size of machines that I can create?

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on datacenter where VM is hosted. This warning means that Standard_D4 is not able to be created in Datacenter when you are hosted in.

2) Here is a link explaining what series of VMs is better in different cases: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/

For example, D is for compute power, G is for memory usage, etc.

First you decide what service you are going to create and what kind of resources you need: huge memory, a lot of CPU resources or network. Once you realize it, you will create an instace with appropriate type. After that you will be able to change size with similar type (from G1 to G2 to add memory). But it doesn't make sence to change from G1 to A as they have different purposes

Comment: What is the algorithm to compute this VM :  `A5, A6, A7, Basic_A0, Basic_A1, Basic_A2, Basic_A3, Basic_A4, ExtraLarge, ExtraSmall, Large, Medium, Small, Standard_D1_v2, Standard_D11_v2, Standard_D12_v2, Standard_D13_v2, Standard_D14_v2, Standard_D2_v2, Standard_D3_v2, Standard_D4_v2, Standard_D5_v2.` ?

Comment: I don't think exact algorithm is available in public, otherwise it should be easy to find. The limitation is based on datacenter.

Answer (score 0):

@ivan_petrushenko, as references, the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2014/11/11/azure-a-series-d-series-and-g-series-consistent-performances-and-size-change-considerations/) introduced the VM size chang considerations, and the other [blog](https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2015/10/11/azure-virtual-machine-resizing-consideration/) shows the tables of all the resizing configuration paths which via testing.

Please refer to the section [`Background information`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-allocation-failure/#background-information) of the article "Troubleshoot allocation failures when you create, restart, or resize Windows VMs in Azure", it explains the work principle for VM allocation.